# Proving first order linear equation using ideas of exact equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms

Write equation 
$$
\tag{1}
dy/dx + P(x)y = Q(x) 
$$ 
in the form $ M \, dx + N \, dy = 0 $ and use the ideas of integrating factors to show that this equation has an integrating factor $\mu$ that is a function of $x$ alone. Find $\mu$ and obtain 
$$
\tag{2}
y=e^{-Pdx}\left(\int \:Qe^{\int \:Pdx}dx+c\right)
$$ 
by solving $\mu M \, dx + \mu N \, dy = 0$ as an exact equation.

**My approach:**

Rearranged terms in $(1)$ to get $\left(Q\left(x\right)-P\left(x\right)y\right)dx-dy=0$ which gave me $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(M\right)=-P\left(x\right)$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(N\right)=0$.

$=>$ $\frac{\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(M\right)-\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(N\right)}{N}=P\left(x\right)$, which solves the first part of question.

Now Integrating Factor is $\mu = e^{\int P\left(x\right)\,dx}$. I multiplied it to equation $(1)$ and solved for $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(f\right)=N$ which gave me $f= -e^{P\left(x\right)\,dx}y+g\left(x\right)+c$. Now solving for $
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(f\right)=M
$
from above equation of $f$ , I am getting $g'(x)= e^{P\left(x\right)\,dx}\left(Q\left(x\right)+\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$ . Usually after reaching this step I find $g(x)$ and substitute it in $f$ found earlier but in this problem I am stuck here and not able to reach equation $(2)$. Please help me in finding out where I am going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: After multiplying by the integrating factor you get an exact equation, whose integral can be found to be of the form $I(x,y)=-y \exp(\int P\,dx)+I_1(x)$. Substituting that into the equation you obtain $I'_1(x)=\int Q\exp(\int P\,dx)\,dx)$. Finally you get $$y=\exp\Bigr(-\int P\,dx\Bigl)\left(\int Q\exp\Bigr(\int P\,dx\Bigr)\,dx+c\right).$$

Comment: Incidentally: why the downvote?

Comment: @user539887 can you explain how you got $I'(x)$? That is the part I am facing difficulties in as you can see I am getting $g'(x)$ something else.

Comment: From the formula, $\frac{\partial I}{\partial x}=-yP(x)\exp(\int P\,dx)+I'_1(x)$. But $\frac{\partial I}{\partial x}$ must be equal to $Q(x)\exp(\int P\,dx)-yP(x)\exp(\int P\,dx)$, so $I'_1(x)=Q(x)\exp(\int P\,dx)$ (here I made a misprint in my first comment, sorry).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I finally solved it. The mistake I was doing was instead of doing partial differentiation wrt x I was doing differentiation which was giving me an extra term!